# How to move the cursor position in zsh widget definition

Tags: zsh, zsh-zle

I have this snippet:

```
insert_sudo () { zle beginning-of-line; zle -U "sudo "; zle end-of-line; }
zle -N insert-sudo insert_sudo
bindkey "\es" insert-sudo
```

But `\es` only appends "sudo" to the end of a line, not the beginning of line as I expected. Please help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following:

```
insert_sudo() { BUFFER="sudo $BUFFER"; zle end-of-line; }
```

This directly modifies the special `$BUFFER` variable containing the contents of the command line by prepending `sudo`  and then placing the cursor at the end of the line.

The problem with `zle -U` is that it only takes effect AFTER the widget finishes. From the `zsh` manual:

> After the widget currently executed ﬁnishes, ZLE will behave as if the
>   characters in the string were typed by the user.

Comment: @AdrieanKhisbe: Good point, thanks - I've updated the answer.